# Generate ABP Authorization Access Token from Service Application(API service) for Mobile Application without password/password grant

Tags: c#, .net-core, abp

I want Access token for social login users with out password and password grant in ABP framework version 4.3 and .Net core 6.

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>() {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Client_Id",_configuration["AuthServer:ClientId"]),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UserName", userName),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password", password),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password")
                };

ResponseTokenDTO response = new ResponseTokenDTO();
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var identityUrl = _configuration["AuthServer:Authority"];
                var url = identityUrl + "/connect/token";
                using (var conn = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData))
                {
                    conn.Headers.Clear();
                    conn.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                    HttpResponseMessage response1 = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, conn);
                    var userDetails = await _appUserRepository.FindAsync(r => r.UserName == userName);
                    if (response1.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        result = await response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
```

How to Get token with out password for google or apple login users because mobile team sharing email address for those users. with out token user not able to access APIs.

```
var tokenValue = "";
try
{
    var claims = new Claim[] {
    new (JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, identityUser.Id.ToString()),
    new (JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, identityUser.Email)
};

    var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
        new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_jwtOptions.SecretKey)),
        SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    var Token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        _jwtOptions.Issuer,
        _jwtOptions.Audience,
        claims,
        null,
        DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
        signingCredentials
        );

    tokenValue = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(Token);
}
```

I tried above code but that token is not accepting ABP.